# how to formulate a recurrence relation for a basic dynamic programming problem

Tags: java

There is a card game that you are dealt with a hand of `n` cards. Different combination of the cards will give you different points. You have m chances to play your cards and you have to play your card in the order that is given to you. To win the game, you need to minimize the total amount of points. You are given n cards, m chances to play and combination points.

For example, you are dealt with a hand of card `{1, 2, 3}` and you can play your cards `2` times so `n = 3` and `m = 2`. `P(1,2) = 12`, `P(2,3) = 50`, `P(1,3) = 2`
you can play your cards as follows

`{1}{2,3}` gives you 50 points

`{1,2}{3}` gives you 12 points  <----- this is the answer

`{1,2,3}{}` gives you 64 points

`{1,3}{2}` gives you 2 points but this is not allowed because we have to follow the order

I am having trouble coming with with a recurrence relation for a dynamic programming approach. Does anyone have ideas? Thanks!

I have tried to do the following recurrence relation

base case: `dp(n, 1) = 64` playing all the cards at once

base case: `dp(1, k) = 0` only have one card

`dp(n-1, m-1)` for if I have the play the first card by itself, and I need to arrange the rest of the cards

`dp(n-1, m)` + some points? This is the part I'm having trouble with. this means the first hand that I play involves a combination of cards with the first card in it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Looks like you are asking a homework question.  Many people are willing to help, if you ask the right types of questions.  See [How Do I Ask Homework Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and follow the advice there.  You will get much better responses.  The key is to make a good-faith attempt and THEN to ask _specific_ questions about _your_ implementation.

Comment: Pick a _single_ language, if you wish to provide supporting code showing what you have tried so far or if you intend to implement this in one.  Pick _NO_ language if you are looking for algorithmic advice.  Please do _not_ just tag a bunch of languages in the hopes of attracting more people to your question.